# *Flycheck error messages* comes up with weird ShellCheck syntax errors

Tags: flycheck, spell-checking

First of all, many thanks for Flycheck. I am using it with Bash scripts, and it works pretty well.

However, every now and then, a buffer named *Flycheck error messages* comes up with a weird error like this:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `)'
`  "$ZENITY_TOOL" --no-markup  --entry  --title "$TITLE"  --text "$HEADLINE_IP_ADDR"  --entry-text="$PREVIOUS_IP_ADDRESS")"'
```

Another example:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `)'
`          )'
```

My guess is that the following is happening: while I type, Flycheck is taking a snapshot of the current Bash source on the fly, and this version fails the syntax check so badly that ShellCheck does not generate the normal output format with source warnings which Flycheck expects and tries to parse.

Before using Flycheck, I checked with "bash -n" (noexec) first, and only called ShellCheck if Bash reported no syntax errors.

I am no expert, but if my guess is right, then maybe Flycheck could take another approach: it could convert the unparsable error from ShellCheck into a normal source code warning in the first line of the script. This way, the user can still inspect the error message, but the annoying *Flycheck error messages* buffer would not randomly come up.